# Shotwell can't export to Picasa -- 401 unauthorized

Tags: shotwell, google-picasa

Publishing to Picasa results in the following error

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo returned HTTP status code 401 unauthorized
```

My "online accounts" in the "system settings" return no error and show that I seem to be connected to my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the "Online Accounts" settings and setting up a new account resolved the problem.

Comment: You should accept your own answer to show that this question is answered now. It worked for me too, so +1